# how to get 5v voltage from digital pins of arduino uno

Tags: arduino

I want 5v voltage from any of the digital pins of arduino uno board but i am getting less than 2v. I also tried to get net voltage of nearly 5v by connecting 3 digital pins to positive terminal and ground pin to negative terminal.
what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage you get from that pin depends on the resistance in the circuit you're drawing power into.  At 20mA current you can expect the output voltage to be ~4.5.  If you're pulling 70ma your voltage is going to be far lower. If you need a constant 5 volts you will have to provide an external "[constant voltage driver](https://blog.adafruit.com/2013/03/06/building-a-simple-constant-current-led-driver/)".  The processor does not have a built-in one. Alternatively, run a separate 5v power supply to your circuit and control it with a [relay](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3191) or [transistor switching circuit](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/relay-switch-circuit.html).